# React app loading css on local but not on heroku

Tags: css, reactjs, heroku, webpack

I coded a react app using webpack and postcss 
locally everything works great

I deployed it on heroku with no errors but the css isn't being loaded at all I couldn't figure out why

This is my webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var AppCachePlugin = require('appcache-webpack-plugin');

 module.exports = function(options) {
     var entry, jsLoaders, plugins, cssLoaders, devtool;

   // If production is true
    if (options.prod) {
    // Entry
       entry = [
  path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/app.js') // Start with js/app.js...
];
cssLoaders = ['file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]', 'postcss-loader'];
// Plugins
plugins = [// Plugins for Webpack
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // Optimize the JavaScript...
    compress: {
      warnings: false // ...but do not show warnings in the console (there is a lot of them)
    }
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'index.html',
    filename: 'index.html', // Move the index.html file...
    minify: { // Minifying it while it is parsed using the following, self–explanatory options
      removeComments: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      removeRedundantAttributes: true,
      useShortDoctype: true,
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
      keepClosingSlash: true,
      minifyJS: true,
      minifyCSS: true,
      minifyURLs: true
    }
  }),
  new AppCachePlugin({
    exclude: ['.htaccess']
  })
];

// If app is in development
 } else {
   devtool = 'cheap-eval-source-map';
// Entry
entry = [
  "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000", // Needed for hot reloading
  "webpack/hot/only-dev-server", // See above
  path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/app.js') // Start with js/app.js...
];
cssLoaders = ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'];
// Only plugin is the hot module replacement plugin
plugins = [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // Make hot loading work
  new AppCachePlugin()
]
}

return {
devtool: devtool,
entry: entry,
output: { // Compile into js/build.js
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  filename: "js/bundle.js"
},
module: {
  loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/, // Transform all .js files required somewhere within an entry point...
      loader: 'babel', // ...with the specified loaders...
      exclude: path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/') // ...except for the node_modules folder.
    }, {
      test:   /\.css$/, // Transform all .css files required somewhere within an entry point...
      loaders: cssLoaders // ...with PostCSS
    }, {
      test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/i,
      loader: "url-loader?limit=10000"
    }
  ]
},
plugins: plugins,
postcss: function() {
  return [
    require('postcss-import')({ // Import all the css files...
      onImport: function (files) {
          files.forEach(this.addDependency); // ...and add dependecies from the main.css files to the other css files...
      }.bind(this) // ...so they get hot–reloaded when something changes...
    }),
    require('postcss-simple-vars')(), // ...then replace the variables...
    require('postcss-focus')(), // ...add a :focus to ever :hover...
    require('autoprefixer')({ // ...and add vendor prefixes...
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'IE > 8'] // ...supporting the last 2 major browser versions and IE 8 and up...
    }),
    require('postcss-reporter')({ // This plugin makes sure we get warnings in the console
      clearMessages: true
    })
  ];
},
target: "web", // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
stats: false, // Don't show stats in the console
progress: true
}
```

}

Comment: Did you solve this?